# Specify order of Rows with ga:dayOfWeekName as dimension

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am making an API call using **ga:dayOfWeekName** as the dimension:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:xxxxxxxxx&dimensions=ga:dayOfWeekName&metrics=ga:pageviews&start-date=2016-12-24&end-date=2017-01-23&max-results=24
```

The data returned is not in **ga:dayOfWeek** order (e.g. Sunday,Monday,Tuesday, etc).  Instead it comes back Friday, Monday, Saturday, etc (see screen shot below).  Nor is it ordering by the metric.  Is there an option to have it return results by the numerical day equivalent?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to sort [ga:dayOfWeekName](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_dayofweekname) as you have mentioned, because it will sort alphabetically only.

If you want to sort in the order that you have mentioned, add one more dimension [ga:dayOfWeek](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_dayofweek) in your API request, which is a one-digit number from 0 (Sunday) to 6 (Saturday) and then add [sort](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#sort) query parameter in your API request.

So your API request should be something like this

`https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:xxxxxxxxx&dimensions=ga:dayOfWeekName,ga:dayOfWeek&metrics=ga:pageviews&sort=ga:dayOfWeek&start-date=2016-12-24&end-date=2017-01-23&max-results=24`

Hope it helps.

Comment: At the end of the day this would work.  But in this application I would then need to suppress the data associated with the **DayOfWeek** dimension.  I may just make and option in my application to replace the numeric value with its corresponding character description.  Thanks for your effort however.